# prove the two following infinite unions/intersections

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove the following infinite unions/intersections:
**$$\boxed{(1)}$$**

> $$\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb {\mathbb N^+}}\left[0,\frac{1}{n}\right]=\left\{0\right\}$$

**$$\boxed{(2)}$$**

> $$\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[n,n+1\right)=\left[1,∞\right)$$

For the first one assume 
$x∈\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb {\mathbb N^+}}\left[0,\frac{1}{n}\right]$

then based on the definition of union we have:
$$∃ \thinspace n∈{\mathbb N^+} :x∈\left[0,\frac{1}{n}\right]$$ or equivalently

:$$∃ \thinspace n∈{\mathbb N^+} :0\le x\le\frac{1}{n}$$

but I don't know how to continue,also for the second one I tried to use limits, but it's not helpful.

Comment: Archimedean property?

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown,I know what is that but how can I use this?

Comment: The first one is an infinite intersection, yet your partial argument treats it as an infinite union.

Comment: @Greg Martin,can you please do a proof?

Comment: Change your "there exists" to "for all", and see what happens from there.

Answer (score 1):

(1) We will prove the two inclusions: $\supset)$ is ok because $0\in [0,\frac{1}{n}]$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. $\subset)$ Let $x$ in the intersection, so $0\leq x\leq \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. If $x\neq 0$ then $n\leq \frac{1}{x}$ for all $n$, but this contradicts the fact that $\mathbb{N}$ hasn't an upper bound (that is the Archimedean property). Therefore $x=0$.

(2) $\subset)$ Is clear because $[n,n+1)\subset (1,\infty)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. $\supset)$ Let $x\in [1,\infty)$ so $1\leq x$. If $x<2$ then $x\in [1, 2)$ and we finish. If not, we assume $x\geq 2$ and do the same thing with 3. There must be an $n$ such that $x\leq n$ (otherwise $\mathbb{N}$ would have an upper bound, absurd) so this process must stop in finite steps. Namely we have $n-1\leq x\leq n$. if $x<n$ or $x=n$ we have $x\in [n-1,n)$ or $x\in [n,n+1)$ respectively.